# How can I make this work without an array?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, counter, pow

The program prints out the sum of the square of the first 12 integers following the number entered by the user. My teacher assigned me this as homework but we haven't studied arrays yet in class; so how can I do it without using them?

**Output example**:

If the users enters:`1` the program should print out the result of(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 and so on)

```
SAMPLE INPUT:1
SAMPLE OUTPUT:650
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int num,i,sum;

void main(){
    int num[13];//cuz stores the first number and the 12 following
    
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    
    for(i=1;i<=num[0]+12;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+pow(num[i],2);
        num[i+1]=num[i]+1;
    }
    printf("sum of the 12 following number each squared:%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: just use an int and increment it on each iteration

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate each numbers and add that to sum. After adding, the calculated numbers can be discarded because they won't be used later.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int num,i,sum=0;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+(num+i)*(num+i);
    }

    printf("sum of the 12 following number each squared:%d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Also:

- Generally, using global variables should be avoided if they can. Note that global variables are implicitly initialized to zero but non-static local variables won't be implicitly initialized.
- You should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.
- `pow()` is for dealing with floating-point number. Floating-point calculation may produce some errors and should be avoided when dealing with integers.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the call to *scanf* was successful.

Answer (score 0):

#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

int main() {

```
int N, I, SUM=0;

printf("Entre any value: "); scanf("%d", &N);

for(I = 0; I < 12; I++)
{
    SUM += pow(N, 2);
    N++;
}
    
printf("%d", SUM);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int num,i,sum;
void main(){
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=1;i<12;i++)
    {
      sum=sum+(num+i)*(num+i);
    }
    printf("sum of the 12 following number each squared:%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: This will calculate for `num+12` numbers starting from `1` instead of requested `12` numbers starting from `num`.